# Twilio programmable chat (JS SDK) tokenAboutToExpire is not working

Tags: angular, twilio, token, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm using Twilio programmable chat in my angular project. Everything is working fine except token regeneration. This
**tokenAboutToExpire** and **tokenExpired** events are not fired even after
token is expired.

***FYI** Console logs written in event handler not logged and that's how it's clear that events aren't fired.*

Below is the code snippet I've used, please help me for the same.

```
Twilio.Client.create(token, {logLevel: 'debug'}).then(async(client: Client) => {
   this.chatClient = client;
   
   this.chatClient.on('tokenAboutToExpire', async() => {
     console.log('token will expire soon');
     this.generateToken(this.id).subscribe((result: any) => {
       const token = result;
       this.chatClient.updateToken(token);
       console.log('token generated');
     });
   });
   this.chatClient.on('tokenExpired', async() => {
     this.generateToken(this.id).subscribe((result: any) => {
       const token = result;
       this.chatClient.updateToken(token);
       console.log('token generated');
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: What is the token experation time with which you are testing?

Comment: Token expiration time is around 1 hour. I've waited till 1 hour and after that, I was getting an error from Twilio (err 401).

Comment: @ХристиянХристов found anything ?

Comment: Unforutnatly no, i had faced similar issue, but the cause was that the refresh interval was too short, so the `tokenAboutToExpire ` was never getting called

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: No, found nothing.

Comment: @KhushiRaval I'm upgrading my Angular 1.x web application with Twilio chat to Angular 12. I have followed the example from https://recursive.codes/blog/post/37. Unfortunately, I stuck with few errors. Could you post your code that how you initiate and import Twilio etc.

Comment: @Sankar Please share your errors, I'll try to help you for same if I can.

Comment: @KhushiRaval thanks, I was able to fix it.